# jQuery: How to change slider animation

Tags: jquery, slider

I have a simple slider in jQuery which rotates images (.tip-image) and text attached to them (.tip-box). I would like to remove the animation from the text (.tip-box) so it will be displayed instantly on changing to next-item, but keep the animation on the image.

```
(function($) {
  $(document).ready( function() {
    $('#training-tips-slider a').click(function(e) {
      var $active = $('.training-tips-post.active');
      var $next = $(this.hash);
      $active.addClass('last-active');
      $active.removeClass('active');
      $next.addClass('active');
      $next.css({opacity:0}).animate({opacity:1}, 800, function() {$active.removeClass('last-active');})

      $('#training-tips-slider a').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
      e.preventDefault();
    });
    });

    var current = 1;
    function autoAdvance() {
        if( current==-1 )
            return false;
        $('#training-tips-slider a').eq(current%$('#training-tips-slider a').length).trigger('click',[true]);
        current++;
    }
    // The number of seconds that the slider will auto-advance:
    var changeEvery = 15;
    var itvl = setInterval( function() { autoAdvance() }, changeEvery*1000 );
})(jQuery);
```

CSS:

```
.training-tips-post {background: #fff; z-index: 8;}
.training-tips-post.last-active {z-index: 9;}
.training-tips-post.active {z-index: 10;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="training-tips-post-1" class="training-tips-post active">
  <div class="tip-image">
    <img class="wp-post-image" height="220" width="680" src="path-to-my-image1.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="tip-box">
    <h2>TIP HEADER 1</h2>
    <p class="tip-text">This a text for item number 1</p>
  </div>

</div> <!-- END of #training-tips-post-1 -->


<div id="training-tips-post-2" class="training-tips-post">
  <div class="tip-image">
    <img class="wp-post-image" height="220" width="680" src="path-to-my-image2.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="tip-box">
    <h2>TIP HEADER 2</h2>
    <p class="tip-text">This a text for item number 2</p>
  </div>
</div>  <!-- END of #training-tips-post-2 -->

<div id="training-tips-post-3" class="training-tips-post">
<div class="tip-image">
<img class="wp-post-image" height="220" width="680" src="path-to-my-image3.jpg">
</div>

<div class="tip-box">
<h2>TIP HEADER 3</h2>
<p class="tip-text">This a text for item number 3</p>
</div>

</div>  <!-- END of #training-tips-post-3 -->

<!-- SLIDER -->
<ul id="training-tips-slider">
  <li><a href="#training-tips-post-1" title="Featuring: TIP 1" class="active">Spánek</a></li>
  <li><a href="#training-tips-post-2" title="Featuring: TIP 2" >Poslušnost psa</a></li>
  <li><a href="#training-tips-post-3" title="Featuring: TIP 3">Spánek</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears your code is fading in each complete `.training-tips-post` div which contains both the image and the text. You could try just fading in the image by changing this line:

```
$next.find(".tip-image").css({opacity:0}).animate({opacity:1}, 800, function() {$active.removeClass('last-active');})
```

Some additional tweaks may be necessary to smooth out the transition, but your text should become visible instantly.

Comment: That is what I thought and I did that, but I was not able to "smooth out" the transition (finish it). I did it with $next.children(".tip-image"). .. (btw what's the difference between find() and children() in this case?)
The image was not changing to each other, but from image-1 to white and then to image-2. Can you help please?

Comment: There a few ways to go about this. The reason it's flashing white is the background color on .training-tips-post. I would need to load up the code before giving a working solution, let me know if you still haven't figured it-

Comment: No, I haven't figure it out myself. I wanted the image to flash white, but not the text - that's why I inserted .training-tips-post {background: #fff;} But the text should be completely without animation and without flashing white (just change into the new text).